# Animate widget on creation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm very new to Flutter and I'm trying to understand animations.

This widget will slide up from bottom to center when rendered.
It seems to work, but I'm uncertain if this is the way to do it.

So what I want is that every time this Text widget is put on the screen it should animate from bottom to center. I did that by calling a function from `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` that changes the state in the `initState` .

Is there a better, cleaner way to this?

```
class AnimatedCenterText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  AnimatedCenterText(this.text);

  @override
  _AnimatedCenterTextState createState() => _AnimatedCenterTextState();
}

class _AnimatedCenterTextState extends State<AnimatedCenterText> {
  AlignmentGeometry _alignment = Alignment.bottomCenter;

  void _changeAlignment() {
    setState(() {
      _alignment = Alignment.center;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _changeAlignment();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedAlign(
      alignment: _alignment,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
      child: Text(
        widget.text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fine. You can do it using `Future` or `Timer`.

Comment: If you want more fine control, use `SlideTransition`.